# Python Get File Length Of Keyboard Buffer

Tags: python, file, keyboard

I am coding a text-based game, and I need to read key presses. For various reasons, I'm doing this by reading the keyboard buffer. This is my current code for that:

```py
while True:
    file = open("/dev/input/event3","rb")
    data = file.read(45)
    character = data[42:43].hex()
    press = data[44:45].hex()
```

The problem is, that the program will wait until it has read 45 bytes. I do not want this, because the program should do other stuff (like recharging mana). So I thought the program could check to see if the file is empty, and if it isn't, there would have been a new key press and I could read it. So I wrote this code:

```py
while True:
    file = open("/dev/input/event3","rb")
    while True:
        if os.stat("/dev/input/event3").st_size > 0:
            data = file.read(45)
            break
    character = data[42:43].hex()
    press = data[44:45].hex()
```

But `os.stat("dev/input/event3").st_size` returned `0`.
I also tried with `os.path.getsize("/dev/input/event3")`, but it also returned `0`.

I have considered threading as a possible solution, but it is a bit too complicated for me, especially with transferring variables from one thread to another (and `Lock()` and similar things are beyond my understanding.

So my question is: Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution, that uses threads, but not that complicated.
Add this function:

```py
def key_listener():
    while True:
        keyboard_buffer = open("/dev/input/event3","rb")
        data = keyboard_buffer.read(45)
        keyboard_buffer.close()
        character = data[42:43].hex()
        press = data[44:45].hex()
        save_file = open(sys.path[0] + "/key.txt", "w")
        save_file.write(character + "\n" + press)
        save_file.close()
key_listen_thread = threading.Thread(target=key_listener, daemon=True)
key_listen_thread.start()
```

To look if a key is being pressed/was pressed:

```py
save_file = open(sys.path[0] + "/key.txt", "r+")
lines = save_file.readlines()
save_file.write("") # Optional, will delete contents of file
save_file.close()
keycode = "21"
press = "01" # 00 = released, 01 = pressed
try:
    if lines[0].replace("\n", "") == keycode and lines[1] == press: # Do something
except IndexError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`os.path.getsize(path)`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.getsize) which will

> Return the size, in bytes, of *path*. Raise [`OSError`](https://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#OSError) if the file does not exist or is inaccessible.

```
import os
os.path.getsize('C:\\Python27\\Lib\\genericpath.py')
```

Or use [`os.stat(path).st_size`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat)

```
import os
os.stat('C:\\Python27\\Lib\\genericpath.py').st_size
```

Or use [`Path(path).stat().st_size`](https://docs.python.org/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.stat) (Python 3.4+)

```
from pathlib import Path
Path('C:\\Python27\\Lib\\genericpath.py').stat().st_size
```

answer taken from this stack: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6591957/edit
from user @Artsiom Rudzenka

In addition to that you should use `sys.path[0]` to get the full path
so it can be like:

```
filename = sys.path[0] + "/dev/input/event3"
```

However you should check the `pathName` and not the opened file.

Comment: They work for a file, but not for the keyboard buffer.

Comment: Oh I didn't understand you want to get for any file because thats in the title, you should change it

Comment: `sys.path[0]` returns the path of the current parent directory. `/dev/input/event3` is already the absolute path.